# Falha com referencias a um pacote nuget

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, uwp

Depois de instalar a Atualização de Aniversário do W10, tenho tentando fazer build de um projeto open source que fazia normalmente antes e agora não consigo.
Recebo o seguinte erro no output do Visual Studio 2015 Update 3:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'GeoExtensions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

O erro não é com o projeto, obviamente, já que existem centenas de pessoas o compilando sem problema.

Já tentei:

- Clean solution
- Bebuild solution
- Checar com o nuget se o pacote está certo
- "restaurar" todos os pacotes nuget
- Desinstalação e instalaçao de todos os pacote.
- Formatar o computador e fazer a instalação mais limpa possível do Visual Studio
- E qualquer outra "solução" que encontrei no stackoverflow ou em qualquer outro site, em vários dias de busca

Mas o problema continua.

Comment: No arquivo packages.config, voce verá todos os packages que o NuGet instalou...Delete a parte relacionada ao GeoExtensions, e tente instalar novamente via NuGet. Acredito que possa ser um problema relacionado ao diretório do package ou referencia mesmo

Comment: @Forlani não resolve. A primeira coisa que tentei foi desinstalar e instalar o pacote. 
// Eu fiz um teste e percebi que instalando o GeoExtensions em outro projeto, funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Tente referenciar a Dll explicitamente `(Project)->References->Add Reference`.

Answer (score 2):

Isso já aconteceu comigo, segue os passos que normalmente resolve meu problema.

1. Faça um "Clean Solution"
2. Feche o Visual Studio
3. Via **Windows Explorer**, vá até a pasta da sua solução
4. Apague a pasta `packages`
5. Abra sua solução no Visual Studio novamente
6. Faça um "Rebuild"

Comment: Não resolve. Simplesmente desisti e fiz um "helper" para substituir o pacote.